# find a special character from string in python and remove the later part

Tags: python, string

I have a pandas dataframe of more than 100,000 news articles.

What I'm trying to do is to find the last `.` so that I can remove the other strange things after the last sentence.

One of the sample document is like this:

```
...Trump questioned the independence of an inspector. blah blah author@hihi.com Plz susbscribe this guys!
```

I thought of using `.split('.')`, return `stringList[:-1]`, and join the list again so that I can remove the later part.

I am not sure this is an optimal way of doing this. Prob I can search `.` from the back?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Regexp: `[^.]*$` will match everything after the last `.` to the end of the string. Then just replace that with an empty string

Comment: If you get rid of everything after the last `.` you will lose part of the author's email address...

Comment: @Nick thx Nick! but that's exactly what I want. I am doing some NLP project, and author's email is not what we are looking for. = ]

Comment: No worries - just wanted to check. You have a good answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 s= '...Trump questioned the independence of an inspector. blah blah author@hihi.com Plz susbscribe this guys!'
>>> '.' in s
True
>>> print(s.rindex('.'))
75
```

This will return the last index where the substring (.) was found and then you can use this information to say hereafter this just delete everything after.

Comment: simple and clean. Thx!